# Lodash debounce+ useEffect function is not called

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lodash

function test23, not called, but in itself
useEffect program enters how to fix it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-goldwasser-3i8775?file=/src/App.js

```
function test123() {
console.log('т12');
}

useEffect(() => {
_debounce(() => test123(), 1000);
});
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Could you create a CodeSandbox where we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: made an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke the function returned by lodash debounce

```js
function test123() {
  console.log('т12');
}

useEffect(() => {
  _debounce(() => test123(), 1000)();
});
```